# Edit TextArea in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, append, jtextarea

I have this method in my `jFrame Training.java`

```
public void editText(String S){
        jTextArea1.append(S);
    }
```

And I called in other class

```
for(int k=0;k<filesX.length;k++){
           try{
               I=ImageIO.read(filesX[k]);
               for(int i=0;i<I.getWidth();i++)
                   for(int j=0;j<I.getHeight();j++){
                        colorAux=new Color(I.getRGB(i, j));
                            r=colorAux.getRed();
                            g=colorAux.getGreen();
                            b=colorAux.getBlue();
                   }
            }catch(Exception e){}
            E.editText("Image #"+(k+1)+"..."+"\n");
 }
```

But the append just work at the end adding the full text but I need to edit the `jTextArea` for each iteration.

Sorry for my bad English and thank you.

**PD. ty @mojo I resolved like you say adding a SwingWorker object...**

Comment: Your blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from updating the UI. Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append()` does exactly what it says. It appends text to the text area. Instead you should use `setText()`

```
public void editText(String S){
    jTextArea1.setText(S);
}
```